# ObjectMapper throwing JsonMappingException for the attribute not present in the JSON string on deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using the Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize and deserialize a Java object. Even if the input JSON string does not have the specific attribute it's throwing an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a
> (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type]

Suppose below is the class

```java
public class Employee {

    private HashMap<Key,String> map = null;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    // getter && setters
}
```

I understand that I have to write the custom deserializer for the map attribute but even if I am not sending this in the
JSON string "{"firstName":"AVD"}", why getting this error? If this is the Jackson default implementation for deserialization
can we change the behavior?

Comment: what type is Key?

Answer (score 1):

I used HashMap<String,String> instead of HashMap<Key,String> and with following change it worked.

mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);